# Eclipse cant work with TortoiseSVN?

Tags: java, eclipse, tortoisesvn

```
System-> Window-7(32 bits)
Eclipse->eclipse galileo
TortoiseSVN->TortoiseSVN-1.6.16.21511-win32-svn-1.6.17
```

When I install **TortoiseSVN** to my system and I restart my Eclipse it gives me error(In Image) ,What happen Actually?

But when I uninstall **TortoiseSVN**  and restart my system Eclipse works fine...

[image]

.log file::

```
!SESSION 2011-12-10 14:06:13.040 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=unknown
java.version=1.6.0_24
java.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc.
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product

This is a continuation of log file F:\Android projects\.metadata\.bak_0.log
Created Time: 2011-12-10 15:28:18.210

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ltk.ui.refactoring 4 10000 2011-12-10 15:28:18.211
!MESSAGE Internal Error
!STACK 1
Java Model Exception: Core Exception [code 273] Problems encountered while deleting resources.
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.BatchOperation.executeOperation(BatchOperation.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaModelOperation.run(JavaModelOperation.java:728)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:1800)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.core.JavaCore.run(JavaCore.java:4694)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.corext.refactoring.changes.DynamicValidationStateChange.perform(DynamicValidationStateChange.java:101)
    at org.eclipse.ltk.core.refactoring.CompositeChange.perform(CompositeChange.java:278)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.corext.refactoring.changes.DynamicValidationStateChange.access$0(DynamicValidationStateChange.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.corext.refactoring.changes.DynamicValidationStateChange$1.run(DynamicValidationStateChange.java:98)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.BatchOperation.executeOperation(BatchOperation.java:39)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaModelOperation.run(JavaModelOperation.java:728)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:1800)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.core.JavaCore.run(JavaCore.java:4694)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.corext.refactoring.changes.DynamicValidationStateChange.perform(DynamicValidationStateChange.java:101)
    at org.eclipse.ltk.core.refactoring.CompositeChange.perform(CompositeChange.java:278)
    at org.eclipse.ltk.core.refactoring.PerformChangeOperation$1.run(PerformChangeOperation.java:260)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:1800)
    at org.eclipse.ltk.core.refactoring.PerformChangeOperation.executeChange(PerformChangeOperation.java:308)
    at org.eclipse.ltk.internal.ui.refactoring.UIPerformChangeOperation.executeChange(UIPerformChangeOperation.java:92)
    at org.eclipse.ltk.core.refactoring.PerformChangeOperation.run(PerformChangeOperation.java:220)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:1800)
    at org.eclipse.ltk.internal.ui.refactoring.WorkbenchRunnableAdapter.run(WorkbenchRunnableAdapter.java:87)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:121)
Contains: Could not delete '/VC California/lib'.
org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.ResourceException: Problems encountered while deleting resources.
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.localstore.FileSystemResourceManager.delete(FileSystemResourceManager.java:257)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.ResourceTree.internalDeleteFolder(ResourceTree.java:351)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.ResourceTree.standardDeleteFolder(ResourceTree.java:793)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Resource.unprotectedDelete(Resource.java:1768)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Resource.delete(Resource.java:724)
    at org.eclipse.ltk.core.refactoring.resource.DeleteResourceChange.perform(DeleteResourceChange.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.ltk.core.refactoring.CompositeChange.perform(CompositeChange.java:278)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.corext.refactoring.changes.DynamicValidationStateChange.access$0(DynamicValidationStateChange.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.corext.refactoring.changes.DynamicValidationStateChange$1.run(DynamicValidationStateChange.java:98)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.BatchOperation.executeOperation(BatchOperation.java:39)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaModelOperation.run(JavaModelOperation.java:728)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:1800)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.core.JavaCore.run(JavaCore.java:4694)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.corext.refactoring.changes.DynamicValidationStateChange.perform(DynamicValidationStateChange.java:101)
    at org.eclipse.ltk.core.refactoring.CompositeChange.perform(CompositeChange.java:278)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.corext.refactoring.changes.DynamicValidationStateChange.access$0(DynamicValidationStateChange.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.corext.refactoring.changes.DynamicValidationStateChange$1.run(DynamicValidationStateChange.java:98)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.BatchOperation.executeOperation(BatchOperation.java:39)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaModelOperation.run(JavaModelOperation.java:728)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:1800)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.core.JavaCore.run(JavaCore.java:4694)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.corext.refactoring.changes.DynamicValidationStateChange.perform(DynamicValidationStateChange.java:101)
    at org.eclipse.ltk.core.refactoring.CompositeChange.perform(CompositeChange.java:278)
    at org.eclipse.ltk.core.refactoring.PerformChangeOperation$1.run(PerformChangeOperation.java:260)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:1800)
    at org.eclipse.ltk.core.refactoring.PerformChangeOperation.executeChange(PerformChangeOperation.java:308)
    at org.eclipse.ltk.internal.ui.refactoring.UIPerformChangeOperation.executeChange(UIPerformChangeOperation.java:92)
    at org.eclipse.ltk.core.refactoring.PerformChangeOperation.run(PerformChangeOperation.java:220)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:1800)
    at org.eclipse.ltk.internal.ui.refactoring.WorkbenchRunnableAdapter.run(WorkbenchRunnableAdapter.java:87)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:121)
Contains: Problems encountered while deleting files.
Contains: Could not delete: F:\Android projects\VC California\lib\admarvel-android-sdk-core.jar.
Contains: Could not delete: F:\Android projects\VC California\lib.
Caused by: org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.ResourceException: Problems encountered while deleting resources.
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Resource.delete(Resource.java:737)
    at org.eclipse.ltk.core.refactoring.resource.DeleteResourceChange.perform(DeleteResourceChange.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.ltk.core.refactoring.CompositeChange.perform(CompositeChange.java:278)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.corext.refactoring.changes.DynamicValidationStateChange.access$0(DynamicValidationStateChange.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.corext.refactoring.changes.DynamicValidationStateChange$1.run(DynamicValidationStateChange.java:98)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.BatchOperation.executeOperation(BatchOperation.java:39)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaModelOperation.run(JavaModelOperation.java:728)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:1800)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.core.JavaCore.run(JavaCore.java:4694)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.corext.refactoring.changes.DynamicValidationStateChange.perform(DynamicValidationStateChange.java:101)
    at org.eclipse.ltk.core.refactoring.CompositeChange.perform(CompositeChange.java:278)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.corext.refactoring.changes.DynamicValidationStateChange.access$0(DynamicValidationStateChange.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.corext.refactoring.changes.DynamicValidationStateChange$1.run(DynamicValidationStateChange.java:98)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.BatchOperation.executeOperation(BatchOperation.java:39)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaModelOperation.run(JavaModelOperation.java:728)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:1800)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.core.JavaCore.run(JavaCore.java:4694)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.corext.refactoring.changes.DynamicValidationStateChange.perform(DynamicValidationStateChange.java:101)
    at org.eclipse.ltk.core.refactoring.CompositeChange.perform(CompositeChange.java:278)
    at org.eclipse.ltk.core.refactoring.PerformChangeOperation$1.run(PerformChangeOperation.java:260)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:1800)
    at org.eclipse.ltk.core.refactoring.PerformChangeOperation.executeChange(PerformChangeOperation.java:308)
    at org.eclipse.ltk.internal.ui.refactoring.UIPerformChangeOperation.executeChange(UIPerformChangeOperation.java:92)
    at org.eclipse.ltk.core.refactoring.PerformChangeOperation.run(PerformChangeOperation.java:220)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:1800)
    at org.eclipse.ltk.internal.ui.refactoring.WorkbenchRunnableAdapter.run(WorkbenchRunnableAdapter.java:87)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:121)
Contains: Could not delete '/VC California/lib'.
org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.ResourceException: Problems encountered while deleting resources.
```

Comment: Can you provide Eclipse log file please?

Comment: @when i click on eclipse its give me error(see image)...

Comment: did you try changing the java path? However, i'm pretty sure some log is being generated. Look for it

Comment: @Samir have you already installed a JRE or JDK library?

Comment: workspace/.metadata/.log

Comment: Please double-check the existence of the file `F:\eclipse\jre\bin\javaw.exe` **If it does exist**, add the path `F:\eclipse\jre\bin` to PATH enviornment variable as follows by pressing Windows key + Break key to open Windows 7 System dialog box and click Advanced System Settings on the left bar to open the Advanced dialog box. Press "Environment Variables" button. Select PATH variable from System variables list and press "Edit..." button. Append the variable value with `;F:\eclipse\jre\bin` (note: semicolon is needed!) **If it doesn't exist**, check your Java installation

Comment: check you JAVA_HOME Path

Comment: @kaissun `JAVA_HOME` environment variable is mandatory for JDK. Whereas, JRE will use Java System property `java.home` which internally refers to the latest JRE version installation in the  Windows registry `HKLM\Software\JavaSoft` [http://javahowto.blogspot.com/2006/05/javahome-vs-javahome.html](http://javahowto.blogspot.com/2006/05/javahome-vs-javahome.html)

Comment: @andreapier see log file in my question

Comment: It seems you have some kind of permission trouble... You can see eclipse cannot delete some file. I guess that Tortoise protects that file against deletes... Try running eclipse as administrator. And please tell where your workspace is located. I hope it is not inside a protected system folder!

Comment: @andreapier But why run Eclipse fine without tortoise svn?

Comment: I bet if you run Eclipse without tortoise svn you won't get those errors. So this must be the problem. You can check it, but remember to delete the log file every time you try with a fresh eclipse install

Comment: Problem is solved i just change path variable  its works fine now,,,,

Comment: @andreapier I concur. I am surprised that installing TortoiseSVN can corrupt Eclipse which it never happen with mine. However, if OP intends to reinstall TortoiseSVN, I suggest him to install it twice and restart Windows 7 later due to a problem with TortoiseSVN setup under Windows 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TortoiseSVN has nothing to do with your eclipse installation. However, by using a plugin like Subversive or Subclipse in Eclipse, there may be shared configuration for both. If you have a problem like that (JDK or JRE error message), try to do the following:

1. Create for the start of eclipse a shortcut or batch file.
2. Include in the shortcut the following information:

   - `-data`: location of the workspace
   - `-vm`: location of your Java exe

So a possible shortcut could look:

```
eclipse.exe -data my-workspace -vm c:\jdk6\bin\javaw.exe
```

This Java version will then used as a default VM in your workspace, if you don't define another. Have a look at the preferences in Eclipse under `Java > Installed JREs`. There you are able to configure more that one JDK, and say which one should be the default one.